# Is it possible to make "paragraph" the default text format in Dreamweaver

Tags: website-design

I often add rows to tables in Dreamweaver once a day and then add text to these.

it is annoying to always have to change the text format to paragraph, is there a way to make paragraph the default format for all text?

Answer (score 2):

You can use snippets to encapsulate the selected text with whatever code you wish.  for instance you can set up a snippet as `<p class='myClass'> </p>` then select `wrap-selection`.  When you select your text from the `snippets` window select your snippet and it will wrap your `html` around the selected text.

You can also create a snippet such as `<tr><td><p>text goes here</p></td></tr>` then all you need to do is double click the snippet to insert this code into the document then you simply copy/paste or type in between the paragraph tags

Also if you open the `preferences` panel under `edit` and select `code hints` select the radio button for `close tags` `After typing "</"` this will auto close the tags for you. So for example you can type `<p>this is my paragraph</` and it will close the tag for you.  This works with all types of tags not just paragraph.